# How to add an alert to switch toggle for multiple answers?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I created a Quiz app. There is one question with five answers, where  the user can choose one of them. However at the moment it's possible to choose more than one answer. How can I add an alert (`UIAlertController`) and a restriction so if the user has already chosen one answer and tries to choose a second one ?

```
var questionIndex = 0
var answersChosen: [Answer] = []

func updateUI() {
        let currentQuestion = questions[questionIndex]
        let currentAnswers = currentQuestion.answers
        let totalProgress = Float(questionIndex) /
            Float(questions.count)

       numberOfQuestion.text = "\(questionIndex+1)/5"
       // navigationItem.title = "Вопрос - \(questionIndex+1)"
        mainQuestion.text = currentQuestion.text
        progressBar.setProgress(totalProgress, animated:
            true)

        updateMultipleStack(using: currentAnswers)
    }

    @IBAction func multipleAnswerButtonPressed(_ sender: Any) {
        let currentAnswers = questions[questionIndex].answers

        if firstSwitch.isOn {
            answersChosen.append(currentAnswers[0])
        }
        if secondSwitch.isOn {
            answersChosen.append(currentAnswers[1])
        }
        if thirdSwitch.isOn {
            answersChosen.append(currentAnswers[2])
        }
        if fourthSwitch.isOn {
            answersChosen.append(currentAnswers[3])
        }
        if fifthSwitch.isOn {
            answersChosen.append(currentAnswers[4])
        }

        nextQuestion()
    }

    func updateMultipleStack(using answers: [Answer]) {

        firstSwitch.isOn = false
        secondSwitch.isOn = false
        thirdSwitch.isOn = false
        fourthSwitch.isOn = false
        fifthSwitch.isOn = false
        firstQuestionLbl.text = answers[0].text
        secondQuestionLbl.text = answers[1].text
        thirdQuestionLbl.text = answers[2].text
        fourthQuestionLbl.text = answers[3].text
        fifthQuestionLbl.text = answers[4].text
    }




    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender:
        Any?) {
        if segue.identifier == "ResultSegue" {
            let resultsViewController = segue.destination as! ResultViewController
            resultsViewController.responses = answersChosen

        }
    }
}
```

[image: App Screenshot]

Comment: Show the code you have attempted or that is not working.

Comment: MwcsMac, please see update post

Answer (score 2):

The approach I'd take would be to separate the user's selection of an answer (UISwitch collection) from processing the selected answer(Submit Answer button). This would allow the user to change their answer. The previous selection is automatically cleared. The answer is final when pressing a "Submit Answer" button (not shown).

[image: multiple_switch_controls]

In this code example, the switches are set as an IBOutlet collection. The tag on each switch is set from 0 to 4. All the switches are connected to an IBAction called switchPressed. A variable called selectedAnswer is  used to identify the user's final picked answer when the "Submit Answer" is pressed.

```
  @IBOutlet var switches: [UISwitch]!

  private let noAnswer = -1
  private var selectedAnswer = -1

  @IBAction func switchPressed(_ sender: UISwitch) {
    // Check if user turned off switch
    guard sender.isOn == true else {
      selectedAnswer = noAnswer
      return
    }

    // Get user's answer and set all switches
    selectedAnswer = sender.tag
    switches.forEach { $0.isOn = false }
    sender.isOn = true
  }


  @IBAction func submitAnswer(_ sender: UIButton) {
    guard selectedAnswer > noAnswer else { return }

    // use selectedAnswer to process answer and go to the next question
    answersChosen.append(currentAnswers[selectedAnswer])
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You could store all the switches in an array named Switches for example and then run a for loop to check if more than one is selected when checking answer.

```
var count = 0
for switchToggle in switches {
  if switchToggle.isOn {
     count += 1
     if count > 1 {
      //Print Warning "only select one"
    }
  } else {
 //append answers
 }
}
```

you could also use this to have multiple answers for certain quiz question

For the warning, you have different options you could use. You could use UIAlertController to display a warning if more than one button is selected but this could become annoying for the user after a while.

Another option could be to use a UILabel which warns the user to only pick one answer. You could animate the label to fade away after a few seconds.

Comment: for questions that only have one answer: instead of a warning, the answer should just be updated to the latest choice. that said, switches shouldn't be used for single choice questions.

Comment: @ɯɐɹʞ What UI controls would be a better choice in this situation?

Comment: Can you explain ho to realize this solution ? "Another option could be to use a UILabel which warns the user to only pick one answer. You could animate the label to fade away after a few seconds."

Comment: @Marcy, a `UIPicker` only allows a single selection, but the best choice would be a `UITableView` and every selection updates the accessory views of the `UITableViewCell`s. @AlexLeo, perhaps you should share [this](https://www.nngroup.com/articles/toggle-switch-guidelines/) with your instructor